# Estimating beta-binomial distribution

Tags: estimation, beta-binomial-distribution

Suppose that I culture cancer cells in *n* different dishes *g₁*, *g₂*, … , *g<sub>n</sub>* and observe the number of cells *n<sub>i</sub>* in each dish that look different than normal.  The total number of cells in dish *g<sub>i</sub>* is *t<sub>i</sub>*.  There is individual differences between individual cells, but also differences between the populations in different dishes because each dish has a slightly different temperature, amount of liquid, and so on.

I model this as a beta-binomial distribution: *n<sub>i</sub>* ~ Binomial(*p<sub>i</sub>*, *t<sub>i</sub>*) where *p<sub>i</sub>* ~ Beta(*α*, *β*).  Given a number of observations of *n<sub>i</sub>* and *t<sub>i</sub>*, how can I estimate *α* and *β*?

Answer (score 10):

You don't necessarily have to go Bayesian on your model, plain maximum likelihood estimation works just fine (though has no explicit solution). Multiple R packages (eg. aod or VGAM) will fit the distribution for you.

Alternatively, you can use the quasi-likelihood based overdispersed binomial model that does not assume a beta-binomial distribution, just adjusts for the overdispersion. The `glm` function with the `quasibinomial` family will fit this model in R.

Answer (score 9):

To fit the model you can use [JAGS](http://www-fis.iarc.fr/~martyn/software/jags/) or [Winbugs](http://www.mrc-bsu.cam.ac.uk/bugs/). In fact if you look at the week 3 of the lecture notes at Paul Hewson's [webpage](http://users.aims.ac.za/~paulhewson/), the rats JAGS example is a beta binomial model. He puts gamma priors on alpha and beta.

Answer (score 4):

You have a hierarchical bayesian model. Brief details below:

Likelihood Function:

$$f(n_i | p_i, t_i) = (t_i n_i) p_i^{n_i} (1-p_i)^{(t_i - n_i)}$$

Priors on $p_i, \alpha, \beta$:

$$pi \sim Beta(\alpha, \beta)$$

$$\alpha ~ N(\alpha_{mean}, \alpha_{var}) I(\alpha > 0)$$

$$\beta ~ N(\beta_{mean}, \beta_{var}) I(\beta > 0)$$

Posteriors are:

$$p_i \sim Beta(\alpha + n_i, \beta + t_i-n_i)$$

$$\alpha \propto I(\alpha > 0) \prod p_i^{(\alpha-1)} exp(-(\alpha-\alpha_{mean})^2) / (2 \alpha_{var})$$

$$\beta \propto I(\beta > 0) \prod (1-p_i)^{(\beta-1)} exp(-(\beta-\beta_{mean})^2) / (2 \beta_{var})$$

You can then use a combination of Gibbs and Metropolis-Hastings to draw from the posterior distributions.